# Calculate Relation within Query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I am currently stuck with a Resultset which Looks as follows:

```
| Month   | LastWeekForMonth | ValueForLastWeekOfMonth |
| 2013-09 |     2013-40      |      981408,27          |
| 2013-10 |     2013-44      |      931209,12          |
| 2013-11 |     2013-48      |      1081302,00         |
| 2013-12 |     2013-52      |      935418,21          |
| 2014-01 |     2014-05      |      911402,11          |
| 2014-02 |     2014-09      |      991201,10          |
```

This I Calculate using the following Query:

```
  SELECT C.Month
        ,RT.[Weekstamp] as LastWeekForMonth
        ,Sum([RevenueValue]) as ValueForLastWeekOfMonth
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[fact_RevenueTable] RT
  INNER JOIN CalenderWeekTable CW on RT.Weekstamp = CW.Weekstamp
  INNER JOIN CalenderTable C on CW.KalenderID = C.KalenderID
  WHERE RT.Probability <= 1
        AND RT.Weekstamp IN ( 
                             SELECT max(CW.[Weekstamp])
                             FROM [Database].[dbo].[CalenderWeekTable] CW
                             INNER JOIN CalenderTable C on CW.KalenderID = C.KalenderID
                             WHERE C.Month >= @FromSQLMonth and C.Month < @ToSQLMonth
                             GROUP BY C.Month
                             )
  GROUP BY RT.Weekstamp,C.Month
```

**What i Need now is:**

```
| Month   | LastWeekForMonth | ValueForLastWeekOfMonth | QuotientToPreviousMonth |
| 2013-09 |     2013-40      |      981408,27          |          1.04           |
| 2013-10 |     2013-44      |      931209,12          |     0.948849880794259   |
| 2013-11 |     2013-48      |      1081302,00         |     1.161180637921587   |
| 2013-12 |     2013-52      |      935418,21          |     0.8650850641171477  |
| 2014-01 |     2014-05      |      911402,11          |     0.9743258151880537  |
| 2014-02 |     2014-09      |      991201,10          |     1.087556292798137   |
```

So what i Need is a new Column which would Show the Quotient between :

ValueForLastWeekOfMonth / *ValueForLastWeekOf***Previous***Month*

now the question to all of you great and always helpfull People:

Is there a way to accomplish this in SQL ?

Since I want to Calculate this within SQL Server (or if else, in SSIS) it means that there could be made use of all the Tools available in SQL Server 2012.

Thanks to you all in Advance, I'm Looking Forward to Hearing from you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT C.Month
        ,RT.[Weekstamp] as LastWeekForMonth
        ,Sum([RevenueValue]) as ValueForLastWeekOfMonth
        ,Sum([RevenueValue])/ 
         LAG(Sum([RevenueValue]))OVER(ORDER BY Month) AS QuotientToPreviousMonth 
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[fact_RevenueTable] RT
  INNER JOIN CalenderWeekTable CW on RT.Weekstamp = CW.Weekstamp
  INNER JOIN CalenderTable C on CW.KalenderID = C.KalenderID
  WHERE RT.Probability <= 1
        AND RT.Weekstamp IN ( 
                             SELECT max(CW.[Weekstamp])
                             FROM [Database].[dbo].[CalenderWeekTable] CW
                             INNER JOIN CalenderTable C on CW.KalenderID = C.KalenderID
                             WHERE C.Month >= @FromSQLMonth and C.Month < @ToSQLMonth
                             GROUP BY C.Month
                             )
  GROUP BY RT.Weekstamp,C.Month
```

Result:

```
|                            MONTH | LASTWEEKFORMONTH | VALUEFORLASTWEEKOFMONTH |       COLUMN_3 |
|----------------------------------|------------------|-------------------------|----------------|
| September, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          2013-40 |               981408.27 |         (null) |
|   October, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          2013-44 |               931209.12 | 0.948849880794 |
|  November, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          2013-48 |                 1081302 | 1.161180637922 |
|  December, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          2013-52 |               935418.21 | 0.865085064117 |
|   January, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          2014-05 |               911402.11 | 0.974325815188 |
|  February, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |          2014-09 |                991201.1 | 1.087556292798 |
```

I think you can rewrite your query like this:

```
  SELECT a.Month,
         a.LastWeekForMonth,
         a.ValueForLastWeekOfMonth,
         a.ValueForLastWeekOfMonth/ 
         LAG(ValueForLastWeekOfMonth)OVER(ORDER BY a.Month) AS QuotientToPreviousMonth 
  FROM(
  SELECT C.Month
        ,RT.[Weekstamp] as LastWeekForMonth
        ,Sum([RevenueValue]) as ValueForLastWeekOfMonth,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.Month ORDER BY RT.Weekstamp DESC) AS rnk
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[fact_RevenueTable] RT
   INNER JOIN CalenderWeekTable CW on RT.Weekstamp = CW.Weekstamp
   INNER JOIN CalenderTable C on CW.KalenderID = C.KalenderID
  WHERE RT.Probability <= 1
   AND C.Month >= @FromSQLMonth and C.Month < @ToSQLMonth
  GROUP BY RT.Weekstamp,C.Month) a
  WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH YourPostedCode AS
(
    SELECT C.Month
        ,RT.[Weekstamp] as LastWeekForMonth
        ,Sum([RevenueValue]) as ValueForLastWeekOfMonth
    FROM [Database].[dbo].[fact_RevenueTable] RT
    INNER JOIN CalenderWeekTable CW on RT.Weekstamp = CW.Weekstamp
    INNER JOIN CalenderTable C on CW.KalenderID = C.KalenderID
    WHERE RT.Probability <= 1
    AND RT.Weekstamp IN ( 
        SELECT max(CW.[Weekstamp])
        FROM [Database].[dbo].[CalenderWeekTable] CW
        INNER JOIN CalenderTable C on CW.KalenderID = C.KalenderID
        WHERE C.Month >= @FromSQLMonth and C.Month < @ToSQLMonth
        GROUP BY C.Month
        )
    GROUP BY RT.Weekstamp,C.Month
)
SELECT c.[Month], c.LastWeekForMonth, c.ValueForLastWeekOfMonth,
    ValueForLastWeekOfMonth / Lag(ValueForLastWeekOfMonth) OVER(PARTITION BY NULL
        ORDER BY c.[Month]) AS QuotientToPreviousMonth 
FROM YourPostedCode c
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer
do you know of any Option without using CTE ?

Comment: 1 Question,
Last line sais: FROM YourPostedCode c
does this mean i have to do the following:
FROM (CODE) AS C ???
meaning i have to have the code twice in it ?

Comment: There's no need to use the code twice.  "YourPostedCode" is the expression name of the CTE.  It's used within the tsql as if it's a table name.

It looks like @Justin gave you a good solution without the CTE.